# Modelling switches & time in NGSPICE

Tags: button, ngspice

I want to model the behaviour of a circuit in response to 'pushbutton' actions by a user.  That is,

1. Initial state;
2. Simulate momentary button press & new state following;
3. Likewise with a different button.

I haven't used NGSPICE for a looong time, and this sort of thing wasn't something I studied even back then.  I haven't found any way to to this, or even to search properly for it, so any suggestions/help/links will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model initial state of a circuit by specifying node voltages at startup (using the .ic statement).

To model the switch you have a couple of options:
1. Switch Model (SW/CSW) (Ngspice manual 3.2.15)
2. Analog Switch  (Ngspice manual 12.2.10)
3. Use a resistance with a parametric value:
Rswitch node1 node2 R=v(controlnode)
Vcontrol controlnode 0 {expression}